# In JQuery removing first character of a string repeat in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an ajaxi page in my html code and have many Divs in the second page . and wrote a function that slices first character of the srting. the problem is everytime that i reload the second page, it slices the first character of the strings over and over again . i want to works only once.
Here is my code for slice:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <div class="removi">,$12547000</div>
      <div class="removi">,$24580000</div>
      <div class="removi">,$78504000</div>
      <script>
        $('.removi').text(function (_,txt) {
          return txt.slice(1);
        });

      </script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear! can you explain lil broadly.

Comment: Are you saying that you update the page via Ajax, and you want to apply the slice only to the items just added and not to any previously updated items from previous Ajax calls? Either way, please [edit] your question to make it clear how the page is updated.

Comment: @nnnnnn i update my page via ajax but slice function runs every time that i update my page . i want to runs only once

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple boolean flag and then check if the code was executed already:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <div class="removi">,$12547000</div>
      <div class="removi">,$24580000</div>
      <div class="removi">,$78504000</div>
      <script>
          if (window._removedAlready !== true) {
            $('.removi').text(function (_,txt) {
              return txt.slice(1);
            });
            window._removedAlready = true;
          }
      </script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that polluting the `window` namespace is not a good idea. Use any boolean variable which is in the main page, but not in your ajax content.

Comment: the code doesn't work to me and it slices again when i reload the second page 2 times. what do u mean by using any boolean variable?

Comment: @inaz Hmm, how do you load this code? I'm not entirely sure.